# read values from file and put them in different textboxe and increment them

Tags: c#, .net, windows

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                 {
                     int counter = 0;
                     string line;

                 // Read the file and display it line by line.
                 System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("E:\\complier.txt");

                 while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                 {
                     string[] la = line.Split(';');

                     string firstName = la[0];
                     string lastName = la[1];
                     //userBox.Text = firstName;
                     //passBox.Text = lastName;

                     counter++;
                 }
```

Comment: whats the problem?? tell your issue?

Comment: where is the question

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess:

```
 userBox.Text += firstName + Environment.NewLine;
 passBox.Text += lastName + Environment.NewLine;
```

This is not a place where we play guessing games, though..

Comment: Well, it would really help if you could clearly __ask what it is you need__. If you want to collect those names, my code would work, if your file reading code works. Does it (read the lines you expect)? Are you stepping into the code with our best friend, the debugger? What do you want to increment??

Comment: actually i want to read file which have text like "username,pass "and want to show  username in one textbox and pass in other textbox and on second button click  it will read second line values

Comment: Even if you have only one line and even if you have no linefeed at the end it should work. Set a breakpoint on one of my lines and look at the local values!!

Comment: can you kindly correct the mistake from above mentioned code ?

Comment: I see no errors. neither in your code, nor in mine. You should check the delimiter though: Is it ';' or '.'? Other than that: What is your problem? Can you use the debugger?? You __need__ to learn that!!